# What does this line of Python code mean?

Tags: python, set

I am translating some code from Python to C++. I came across the following:

```
set(x for listX in listY for x in listX)
```

I am quite well-versed in C++ and know some basic constructs in Python. In the above code, I know that a set is being created but I do not understand the code inside the brackets. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

listY is probably something like the structure below, so the expanded code is:

```
listY = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = set()
for listX in listY:
    for x in listX:
        result.add(x)
```

notice: sets won't allow duplicate entries

Comment: The generator expression has been passed to `set`, so everything is evaluated immediately - inside the `set` implementation, sure.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [generator comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), analogous to a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) for some info comparing them.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found a similar example in [generator comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)